# Mongoose doesn't update

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I was recently working on an endpoint, and I encountered a problem: the Mongoose doesn't update an entry.

```js
export const playersTurn = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    [...]
    let symbol: 'X' | 'O';
    room.roomPlayers.forEach((player) => {
      if (player.id === id) symbol = player.symbol;
    });
    room.board[row][column] = symbol;
    room.save();
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Your turn has been registered!',
      status: 201,
    });
  } catch {
    return next({
      status: 500,
      message: 'Unexpected error occured!',
    });
  }
};
```

And here's the schema, also:

```js
const roomSchema = new Schema(
  {
    [...]
    board: [
      [String, String, String],
      [String, String, String],
      [String, String, String],
    ],
    [...]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Can someone please explain, why is this not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use await room.save() and add logs to see the errors. catch (err) { console.log(err.message) } ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `markModified`. Now works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an await in your code

`await room.save();`